# Is there a way to set the maxMenuHeight of react-select dropdown based on the height of the options?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I would like to restrict the height of the react-select dropdown to show only the first 5 options, and then allow for scrolling to view any additional options. The options are not necessarily all the same height so is there a way to set the maxMenuHeight based on the first 5 options?

Answer (score 3):

You can use maxMenuHeight props, from the docs :

> maxMenuHeight number = 300 
> Maximum height of the menu before scrolling

[minimizing height of react-select-dropdown](https://react-select.com/props#select-props)